# create React app + php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

Как выстроить такую схему работы: 
получать данные из бд в react компоненты и делать live-reload?
На данный момент данные синхронизируются с бд, но приходится разрабатывать на самом хостинге, что неудобно

Comment: в каком смысле live reload? php и react могут дружить используя SOAP, RESTful  ..

Comment: RESTful используется